# What is the difference between example.com, www.example.com and example.com/?

Tags: redirect, web, dns, directory, subdomain

I have 3 questions mainly. There are questions like this in the Internet, however I have not found a duplicate question like this in StackOverflow. Anyway, I will appreciate your answer.

1. I know that `www.example.com` is a subdomain of `example.com`. So I assume it means that hypothetically I can have two different websites in those two different urls although not recommended. Am I missing something here?
2. Between `example.com` and `example.com/` if you don't do a 301 redirect, then will `example.com/` show a page directory?
3. Why do big companies like Google, Amazon, etc. redirect their domain to the www subdomain? (legacy, convention, best practice?)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In the future, please ask questions like this there instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really related to programming hence a little off topic here.
For further questions like this have a look at the Webmasters StackExchange website instead, or the ServerFault one for configuration issues.

To answer it quickly based on your title, first two are hostnames, last one with `/` is an URL.

To go back to your three points:

1. Yes you can have completely different websites at each name, so `www.example.com` and `example.com` do not need technically to show the same website. It might however confuse a lot of people.
2. Each website will show content based on its configuration. Per se it is impossible to say what will `example.com/` show. It can be a page, a redirection, a file listing, an error... No one knows in advance it depends on the configuration at the moment you query it.
3. Partly subjective: there is a part being a convention and another technical part because it is a little more complicated to use a CDN or other external resources at apex (`example.com`) because you can not use a `CNAME` record in the DNS there, where you can for `www`.  See for example how `www.amazon.com` is a `CNAME` to a CDN.

Answer (score 0):

There is a important difference between *example.com* and *[www.exmaple.com](http://www.exmaple.com)*.

It is local storage!

local storage is not same between *example.com* and *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*.
So even if you save A in local storage in *exmaple.com*, there is not A in local storage in *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*.
In reverse, if you save B in local storage in *[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)*, there is not B in local storage in *example.com*.
LocalStorage is not same between *example.com* and *www.example.com*!!!